# Overwrite rows in one array using another array when two columns are shared between the arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, mapping

I got 2 arrays. In first one field number is empty:

```
array (
  3 => array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => 1, 'number' => 0, 'time' => 40,),  ),
  4 => array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => 2, 'number' => 0, 'time' => 40, ), ),
  5 => array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => 3, 'number' => 0, 'time' => 40, ), ),
  6 => array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => 1, 'number' => 0, 'time' => 41, ), ),
  7 => array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => 2, 'number' => 0, 'time' => 41, ), ),
  8 => array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => 3, 'number' => 0, 'time' => 41, ), ),
)
```

In the second one fields number are not empty, however the array is bit different, because it doesn't have a 2 arrays in the middle (`id = 3`, `time = 40` and `id = 3, time = 41`).

```
array ( 3 => array ( 'id' => '1', 'number' => '3785', 'time' => '40', ),
        4 => array ( 'id' => '2', 'number' => '1574', 'time' => '40', ),
        5 => array ( 'id' => '1', 'number' => '2954', 'time' => '41', ),
        6 =>  array ( 'id' => '2', 'number' => '2463', 'time' => '41', ),
)
```

What I want to do is to some sort of merge of this arrays into one looking like this:

```
array (
    3 => array ( 'id' => '1', 'number' => '3785', 'time' => '40', ),
    4 => array ( 'id' => '2', 'number' => '1574', 'time' => '40', ),
    5 => array (  0 => array ( 'id' => 3, 'number' => 0, 'time' => 40, ), ),
    6 => array ( 'id' => '1', 'number' => '2954', 'time' => '41', ),
    7 => array ( 'id' => '2', 'number' => '2463', 'time' => '41', ),
    8 => array (  0 => array ( 'id' => 3, 'number' => 0, 'time' => 41,), ),
)
```

I tried some variations of `array_merge()` and `array_combine()`, but neither of them seems to work, or perhaps I've been using them badly.

Again, notice how row `5` and `8` are not affected because (`id = 3` and `time = 40`) and (`id = 3` and `time = 41`), respectively, are not represented in the second array.

What I tried and it works, but it doesn't look well in my opinion:

```
foreach($arr2 as $wpis2){
    foreach($arr as $key=>$wpis){

        if($wpis2['id'] == $wpis[0]['id'] && $wpis2['time'] == $wpis[0]['time']){
            $arr[$key] = $wpis2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup got the spec, now how far have you got with writing some code

Comment: I don't see any logic how the arrays should merge. Please describe how it should merge and when to overwrite and when to keep an element.

Comment: You really do not want to make that "WHat I want" array, with different lloking arrays in it. That will make processing it so much more complex and prone to error! ___Uniformity makes processing much easier___

Comment: As @Villanelle says, your "I WANT" array does not make sense as you have a `5` occuracance in both the first and second array, why does the `5` occurance in the `I WANT` array not get flattened and the `number` added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to iterate over the first array in order to populate a key-map based on the combination of `id` and `time` values from all rows.

Use a second loop to iterate over the second array and access the correct key to overwrite by leveraging the mapping array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/V4sUS))

```
$map = [];
foreach ($first as $k => [['id' => $id, 'time' => $time]]) {
    $map["{$id}_{$time}"] = $k;
}

foreach ($second as $row) {
    $key = $map["{$row['id']}_{$row['time']}"];
    $first[$key] = $row;
}
var_export($first);
```